# How can I add different icons in the legend

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I have this chart http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/2169/, I want to add different icons in the legend but I dont know How can do it.

```
labelFormatter: function () {
    $scope.data = this.total;
    console.log($scope.data);
    return '<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/must-have/256/Check-icon.png" width="15" height="15"></span>' + this.y + ' (' + this.percentage.toFixed(2) + '%) - ' + this.name;
},
```

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to achieve in a little more detail please. Do you want different icons for _all_ the items in the legend, or do you want to use different icons depending on attributes of the item?

Comment: For example in the field App Android I want to add android icon, in App iOS I want to add icon iOS, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite an extensive list, so you'll need to manually map out what images you'd like to use for each item. I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/2183/) which illustrates how to do this using a switch statement.

To make it a bit quicker I've used [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) which i'd recommend looking in to:

```
labelFormatter: function () {
    $scope.data = this.total;
    var labelName = this.name,
        icon = '';

    switch(labelName){
        case 'APP Android':
            icon = 'android';
            break;
        case 'APP Ios':
            icon = 'apple';
            break;
        default: // If no match is found, revert to a check icon
            icon = 'check'
    }
    return '<i class="fa fa-' + icon + '"></i> ' + this.y + ' ('+ this.percentage.toFixed(2) +'%) - ' +this.name;
},
```